# Adding AND Statement to SQL lite Delete Function - Crashing App

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I am attempting to erase a record on the entry of BOTH the first name and last name, for obvious reasons. My attempt is the following (My Delete On Click Listener):

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (fname.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 ||
        lname.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
        showMessage("Error", "Please enter First and Last Name");
        return;
    }

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE fname='" + fname.getText() + "' AND lname='" + lname.getText() + "''", null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM customer WHERE fname='" + fname.getText() + "' AND lname='" + lname.getText() + "''");
        showMessage("Success", "Record Deleted");
    }
    else {
        showMessage("Error", "Invalid First and Last Name");
    }
    clearText();
}
});
```

The error I am receiving is on line 72, which is the Cursor.

What am I not doing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to the comment:-

> not too sure about prepared statements, but wouldn't mind learning
> about one in this context if you would like to give code for one

Here's a direct adaptation of your code that swaps from using the  `rawQuery` and `execSQL` methods to the `query` and `delete` convenience methods that prepare the statements.

The code also fixes an issue that would perhaps confuse you or even be the actual problem in that you need to use the `toString` method (as you have previously) to get the data in the EditTexts.

```
    String whereclause = "fname =? AND lname + =?"; //<<<< Where statement with ?'s for arguments
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{
            fname.getText().toString(), // First arg for first ?
            lname.getText().toString()  // Second arg for second ?
    };
    
    Cursor c = db.query(
            "customer", //<<<< table name
            null, //<<<< equates to * (all columns)
            whereclause, //<<<< the WHERE clause (less WHERE keyword)
            whereargs, //<<<< the argumnets to replace the ?'s (will be escaped/enclosed in quotes for you)
            null,
            null,
            null
    );

    //<<<<< REPLACED Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE fname='" + fname.getText() + "' AND lname='" + lname.getText() + "''", null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        db.delete(
                "customer",
                whereclause,
                whereargs
        );
        //<<<<< REPLACED db.execSQL("DELETE FROM customer WHERE fname='" + fname.getText() + "' AND lname='" + lname.getText() + "''");
        showMessage("Success", "Record Deleted");
    } else {
        showMessage("Error", "Invalid First and Last Name");
    }
```

Notes :-

- You should use the `toString` method to get the contents of the EditText.

#### Additional

However as the convenience `delete` method returns the number of rows that have been deleted, as an int, the query, to check for the existence is superfluous, so the above could be simplified to :-

```
    String whereclause = "fname =? AND lname + =?"; //<<<< Where statement with ?'s for arguments
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{
            fname.getText().toString(), // First arg for first ?
            lname.getText().toString()  // Second arg for second ?
    };
    if (db.delete(
                "customer",
                whereclause,
                whereargs) > 0) {
        showMessage("Success", "Record Deleted");
    } else {
        showMessage("Error", "Invalid First and Last Name");
    }
```

You may wish to consider looking at the following for more information :-

- [SQLiteDatabase - delete](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete)
- [SQliteDatabase - query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query_11)

  - Note, there are 4 query methods (plus there are other convenience methods such as `insert` and `update`)

Answer (score 2):

You should seriously consider using a prepared statement here, as it would handle the issue of properly escaping all the literals in your `DELETE` statement.  As I don't know which framework you are using, I won't give code for one.  For an immediate fix to your problem, remove the extra single quote appearing after the last name:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE fname = '" + wfname.getText();
sql += "' AND lname = '" + lname.getText() + "'";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Comment: Ahhh, you are right about the single quote. That little guy snuck in there; thank you! I actually was just noticing the quote differentiation before I saw your comment!

Comment: I am working within Android Studio, in a very basic class about SQLite, so not too sure about prepared statements, but wouldn't mind learning about one in this context if you would like to give code for one

Comment: I don't know how you are connecting to SQLite, so I can't suggest one.  While I've done some Android work, I have never used SQLite with Android.